# innerHTML td tag styling

Tags: for-loop, html-table, styling

```
   function addition(id)
   {
       var myTable  = ref.document.getElementById(id);`enter code here`
       var newRow = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
       var newTd1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
       var newTd2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
       var rowlen = eval(myTable.rows.length);

       newTd1.innerHTML = '<INPUT TYPE=TEXT ..............">';
   }
```

I want to give width and some style to

... Can you please help me with this one?

Comment: Do you want to create a table dynamically with a style ?  Are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: Want to create table dynamically but I am not using bootstrap... I was able to do with newTd1.setAttribute("width","80");

Comment: If you put your code in jsfiddle and explain with more details what you want it will be better to help you.